# Просмотр новых сообщений без прокрутки страницы

Tags: html, css, чат

Есть див, в него добавляются сообщения, пока размер сообщений не превышает размер дива - все отлично, прокручивать стр не надо, но когда превышает - надо. Скажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему.

Comment: Так чем вам помочь? За вас прокручивать страницу? Или какую помощь вы хотите? Весь мир мучается, страдает и скроллит, когда контент не вмещается в область видимости экрана.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я Вас правильно понял, то можно использовать [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). И, как пример, для вашего случая http://jsfiddle.net/V4K4N/ .

```js
$("#add").click(function() {
  $("#content").append("<div class='block'>Сообщение<br>в<br/>несколько строк</div>");
  var height = $("body").height();
  $("body").animate({
    "scrollTop": height
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
#content {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <div id="add">
    click
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Вы меня правильно поняли, но решение неверное, в вашем примере просто происходит скролл при добавлении нового сообщения, а т.к. это "живой" чат, то просмотреть историю переписки будет фактически невозможно, будет постоянно кидать вниз=> вариант не подходит.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/V4K4N/1/

Answer (score 0):

Можно заставить скроллиться сам DIV - сойдёт? На скриншоте в красном обведено то что вам нужно.

[image: Div Scrolling]